# I cannot install python-numpy

Tags: 14.04, python, numpy

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot install numpy.

here is my attempt:

```
ohad@ohad-Vostro-3300:~$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
[sudo] password for ohad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-numpy : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                         liblapack.so.3
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ohad@ohad-Vostro-3300:~$ sudo apt-get install liblapack3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblapack3 : Depends: libgfortran3 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ohad@ohad-Vostro-3300:~$
```

Thanks,

Comment: did you familiar with easy_install from setup.py? use easy_install to get python library will save you a lot of times.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy python-numpy liblapack3 liblapack.so.3 libgfortran3`

Answer (score 0):

Enter these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Try to fix the broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And enter again `sudo apt-get -f install`.

This should solve your dependency problems and you can now install your package.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was good to instal `python-dev` package before.